# How can I check if key is empty for IF Statement Inside a FOR Loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

The line in question is...

```
if(listContent[Source].properties === ""
```

I need it to check if the "Source" key has any value. It's currently not outputting anything. What is proper syntax for this?

Here is the full code:

```
if (visibleFeatures) {
  var uniqueFeatures = getUniqueFeatures(visibleFeatures, "arrayIndex");

  for (var i = 0; i < uniqueFeatures.length; i++) {
    if (listContent[Source].properties === "") {
      listContent += '<div class="dealer"><h3><a href="' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.arrayIndex + '" class="location-heading">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Name + '</a></h3><p class="address">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Address + '<br>' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.City + ',&nbsp;' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.State + '&nbsp;' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Zip + '</p><p class="phone"><a href="tel:+1' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Phone + '">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Phone + '</a></p></div>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<div class="dealer"><h3><a href="' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.arrayIndex + '" class="location-heading">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Name + '</a></h3><p class="address">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Address + '<br>' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.City + ',&nbsp;' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.State + '&nbsp;' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Zip + '</p><p class="phone"><a href="tel:+1' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Phone + '">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Phone + '</a></p><p class="bl-map-link"><a href="https://test.com/">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Source + '</a></p></div>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: listContent is a string, right?

Comment: `Source` is a key name (string), not a variable. Quote it.

Comment: Also, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a cleaner, more modern way of iterating over an array.

Comment: @James - variable string, yes

Comment: @isherwood - quoted it and changed to foreach, still not outputting anything

Comment: What's your intention with `listContent[Source].properties`?  Strings don't have properties like that.

Comment: If `Source` is not a dynamic value then
`if (listContent.Source.properties === "")` OR `if (listContent.Source?.properties)`

Comment: Hard to help without data. Put some, along with your code, in a demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: @James I'm pulling this from Mapbox. Source is the name of the field and I need my code to check if that field is empty of not.

Comment: @MuhammadOvi "Source" is the field name in mapbox. If that has value, it will output the value when I just write the code below without an if statement.

`listContent += '<p class="map-link"><a href="#">' + uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Source + '</a></p>`

Comment: Maybe you could console.log some of the `listContent[Source].properties` so we can better understand what you mean. If it is really a string, even when empty, you could try `listContent[Source].properties.length === 0` or something like that...

Comment: Did you mean for the if to check uniqueFeatures?   `if (uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Source)` ?

Comment: @James I thought of that too because the logic just makes sense but this doesn't work. Essentially, yes, we are checking if `uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Source` has any value. This line retrieves the value of the "Source" field in mapbox.

Comment: @James just to edit my last comment. Your code does work but it still outputs "undefined" and links to [test.com](http://test.com) instead of not showing the source/link part. It's supposed to only show that if the Source field is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much for all the help. I was able to figure out my error.

`!!uniqueFeatures[i].properties.Source`

The `!!` is what made the difference. I'm still researching why this works and  why this doesn't `if (strValue === "")`.